# Adding a decision column to dataset using R

Tags: r

I have a data set "activityData" as follows

```
subject activity       
1        walk   
2        lay       
3        sit   
4        stand     
5        run     
6        walk   
7        sit       
8        run
```

*I wanted to add one more column "active" which should be fill-up with "TRUE" or "FALSE"*

Example:

```
activityData$active <- with(activityData, ifelse( ((activity=="walk") || (activity=="run"), "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

Hope the above statement will merge the column "active" to activityData and looks like as below

```
subject activity active      
1        walk    TRUE
2        lay     FALSE
3        sit     FALSE
4        stand   FALSE
5        run     TRUE
6        walk    TRUE
7        sit     FALSE
8        run     TRUE
```

Can someone help me with correct **R** syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is fast and easy to follow. It makes use of the %in% operator.

```
activityData$active <- activityData$activity %in% c("walk","run")
```

Comment: Great!!! can you post the command to summarized view of activity and active columns?

Comment: maybe unique(activityData[,2:3]) will give you what you're looking for. Should show a number of rows equal to unique activity values with the associated TRUE or FALSE in the second column.